# Unittest not testing (python)

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

This is my code:

```
import unittest

from sallad.Puppgift import Kundenssallad

class Test_kundenssallad(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_av_objekt(self):
        namn = "Grekisksallad"
        slutpris = 60
        tillval = "gurka"
        kundenssallad = Kundenssallad(namn, slutpris, tillval)
        self.assertIsInstance(kundenssallad, Kundenssallad)
        self.assertEqual(kundenssallad.slutpris, 60)
        self.assertEqual(kundenssallad.tillval, "gurka")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Upon running this code in PyCharm, I get:

```
Testing started at 11:32 ...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I expected the program to print something like:

```
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Why do the tests not seem to execute?

Comment: Try with tracing prints to see if your `test_av_objekt`-method doesn't get past some point, or if it manages to execute to its end.

Comment: They execute in the PyCharm Run window, using the test-oriented layout. If you'd like, I can make a little animated gif to show you.

Comment: Also, note the nature of the command that is doing the running...PyCharm has Python call /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py with an argument of your filename. The utrunner.py manages the running of your tests, hence utrunner in the filename.

Answer (score 1):

You have not told unittest what test suite to run.
pycharm not matching the if **name** == "**main**" ?
Try add some debug and print **name**.

Run it something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Test_kundenssallad)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```